# Updating a binary value in a MySQL table from a form

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have this field in a table that is created from a mysql database.

Each row has a color green, orange or red (more or less like a light sign)

At the beginning of this table I have a buttom that submits, (or I would like it to) a value that updates the mysql table, it is binary and selects a blue color (blue image) that indicates that row has been selected.

I would like it to change back on the second click, and so on.

So basically I have rows with a image green orange or red, that on click of the submit button tells the mysql table to change the binary value and replaces the image with a blue one.

The values depend on the primary key "keyword" (This is an SEO script).

The short version of the code is this:

```
<th>";
if ($AveragePR < 2){ echo "$green_button";}
else if ((2 <= $AveragePR) && ($AveragePR< 4)){ echo "$orange_button";}
else if (4 < $AveragePR){ echo "$red_button";}
</th>


<td>
<form action='index.php' method='$_POST'>
<input type=hidden name='keyword' value='$keyword'>
<input type='submit' value = 'SELECT' >
</form>";

$name = mysql_reaL_escape_string($_POST['keyword']);

$query2 = "UPDATE keywords SET column1 = 0 WHERE 'keyword' = '$name'";

</td>
```

Comment: Check the meaning of `'` (and `"`) and `\`` in the MySQL reference manual. Hint: if `'` means "string literal", how would the WHERE be treated? (Also, see placeholders to avoid having to care or use a really annoyingly long function name!)

Comment: Please, do not use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's a deprecated, dangerous interface that's being removed in future versions of PHP. It's usually [quite easy to convert to PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) where you'll have a reliable SQL escaping mechanism and support in PHP 5.5 and beyond.

Comment: What is `method='$_POST'` supposed to mean? Do you mean `method="POST"`?

Comment: Hello.
So I’ve narrowed down the problem to this:
Can anyone tell me why this INSERT command doesn’t work?           "UPDATE keywords SET Adds = 1 WHERE  keyword = 'paper'";

Answer (score 0):

Use **mysql_query** to exec queries in PHP.

```
$query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE keywords SET column1 = 0 WHERE 'keyword' = '$name'");
```